# Allow SSH access but restrict root's access to a given set of IPs

Tags: security, root, sshd, pam

I want to allow SSH for all users as normal *except* that I want to restrict root's access based on a set of IP addresses. So, users `peter`, `paul`, `lary` can login from anywhere, but `root` may login only from hosts `a.b.c.d` and `q.r.s.t`.

- `sshd_config`'s `AllowUsers` won't work for this. If I specify anything, then I must specify all users.
- Unlike how the man pages suggest, `AllowGroups` is checked unconditionally, even if the user is whitelisted in `AllowUsers`; so if I tried to white list non-root users by putting them in a group, and then add the group to `AllowGroups`, the authentication will still fail because root is not in a valid allowed group.
- `sshd_config`'s `DenyUsers` might work if I can somehow whitelist the set of IPs root is otherwise denied from. If I had only one IP, it might work with the `!` operator.
- I can do this partially with the `options` key in the authenticated_keys file *and* by completely disabling the root password. The problem is that this file is not system-policy and may be overwritten by another (root-access) user. Currently, it's the best option I got, and I don't like it. Also, if I nuke the root password, someone in my group will be very angry with me. (If I don't nuke the root password, someone can login via root with the password from any IP.)
- I tried to do this with PAM, specifically via `pam_listfile`, but my approach didn't seem to work at all:

  ```
  auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
  auth       required     pam_listfile.so file=/etc/root-whitelist.txt sense=allow item=rhost apply=root
  auth       include      password-auth
  ```

  Inside the `root-whitelist.txt` file was allowed IP addresses, line by line. I could not get the rule to *deny* non-listed IPs access.

Is the `pam_listfile` approach usable and I simply got it wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8):

My work-colleague pointed me to the same direction as /u/meuh did, using a slightly different approach.

```
Match Address "172.24.*.33"
  PermitRootLogin yes
Match Address "192.168.1.18,192.168.1.20"
  PermitRootLogin yes
```

Comment: Tested against normal users from all IPs (success expected, successful login), against root users from whitelist IPs (success expected, successful login), against root users from non-whitelisted IPs (fail expected, failed to login), and against a non-whitelisted IP which was then whitelisted (success expected, successful login)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your version of ssh, you might be able to set a match condition
around your AllowUsers. `man sshd_config` lists the allowed commands under Match. If AllowUsers is in there, you might try the following.Make sure it is at the end of the file.

```
Match User root
 AllowUsers root@ a.b.c.d root@q.r.s.t
```

Eg, not in OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian, but ok in OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu.

Comment: On our RHEL6 based system, sshd is OpenSSH_5.3p1, and "AllowUsers" is not allowed in a Match block. Tsk. But great idea!

Answer (score 2):

Another work-colleague pointed me in the direction of the **pam_access** module. This uses the format typically found in `/etc/security/access.conf`, but any file can be specified; it can be enabled for the entire system, or only the sshd process. I haven't tried this, but presumably I can set up pam_access using the defaults (on RHEL) by adding it to the `auth` section in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Then the `access.conf` file looks like this:

```
+ : root : hosta hostb hostx
- : root : ALL
```